# Understanding Sign in with Apple using Django Rest Framework (DRF)

Tags: authentication, django-rest-framework, oauth-2.0, sign-in-with-apple

I am trying to implement Sign in with Apple in my iOS app and Django Rest Framework (DRF) application. I want to know if I understand the workflow correctly.

Currently, I am using the libraries [python-social-auth](https://github.com/python-social-auth) and rest_social_auth, and rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication for authentication. The problem is that I set the refresh tokens to expire in one week (this should really be one day). At that point, I need to use the refresh token that Apple originally returned in their first authentication request, but python-social-auth does not persist those.

Specifically, I am wondering how I can get access to those original refresh tokens. More generally, I am wondering if this functionally has already been written in python-social-auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a year and a half, "I" finally figured this out.

I was conflating the device Sign in with Apple with the Sign in with Apple Rest API. If you are developing in iOS/React Native, you do not need to make any calls to the Sign in with Apple Rest API.

You do need to make a call to an Apple *auth* server, but not a Sign in with Apple Rest API server. The Apple auth server will return a public key that you use to then confirm the authenticity of the identity token that Apple send to you on the device.

I borrowed heavily from this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/aamishbaloch/2f0e5d94055e1c29c0585d2f79a8634e), but I believe it is outdated because Apple is now cycling through (at least at the time of this post) 3 different keys. I also used [Chris Herbert's post](https://blog.curtisherbert.com/so-theyve-signed-in-with-apple-now-what/) as a resource.

```
def _fetch_apple_public_key(kid):
    global APPLE_LAST_KEY_FETCH
    global APPLE_PUBLIC_KEYS

    apple_public_key = APPLE_PUBLIC_KEYS.get(kid)
    if (APPLE_LAST_KEY_FETCH + APPLE_KEY_CACHE_EXP) < int(time()) or apple_public_key is None:
        keys_payload = requests.get(APPLE_PUBLIC_KEY_URL).json()
        for key_payload in keys_payload["keys"]:
            if key_payload.get('kid') == kid:
                APPLE_PUBLIC_KEYS[kid] = RSAAlgorithm.from_jwk(json.dumps(key_payload))
                APPLE_LAST_KEY_FETCH = int(time())

    return APPLE_PUBLIC_KEYS[kid]
```

You can get the kid from the header of the identity token:

```
headers = jwt.get_unverified_header(user_token)
kid = headers.get('kid')
```